# Strapi API register returning a 400 error

Tags: api, authentication, settings, strapi, registering

I’ve been creating a web app with a login and a registration function and so far everything has been going great. I managed to connect the app to the api/auth/local api endpoint and send some nice post requests.

Now, I’ve been trying to send requests to the http://localhost:1337/api/auth/local/register endpoint and without any success. I’ve been doing this according to:

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/users-permissions.html#registration

I keep getting a 400 error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "name": "ApplicationError",
    "message": "An error occurred during account creation",
    "details": {

    }
  }
}
```

If I try to send a request with an email that’s already registered in strapi, the response will give me the correct error:

```
{
  "data": null,
  "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "name": "ApplicationError",
    "message": "Email is already taken",
    "details": {
    }
  }
}
```

In the public and authenticated user roles, I’ve allowed every single one of them, for now.
Enable confirmation emails are set to false.

[Email confirmation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Svovz.png)

[Public user permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuaTM.png)

For the headers, I’m using Content-type : application/json

the raw json body I'm posting:

```
{
  "email": "manager1@strapi.io",
  "password": "testtest1",
  "username": "manager1"
}
```

This is my first project with strapi and so far it went pretty well. I’m not sure if I’m missing out on something or if I’m doing something else wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it wasn’t as complicated as I expected.

In the user I had different fields, like `firstName`, `lastName` etc. All of these fields were required.

I made the fields not required, and now it works.